# Draw a Bar chart in SSRS with marker

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bar-chart

I want to create a bar chart in SSRS with a marker at its end similar to below

[image]

Can anyone please suggest a good approach for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add some effort you have tried to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Richards. I tried this but this didn't work for me. Now I achieved this by using matrix and conditional visibility on image.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bar chart to the report. Add chart data to this as appropriate based on your data. While in the designer, right-click on one of the bars in the chart area, and choose Series Properties. Click markers, and choose Diamond from the Marker type combo box. Click OK. Run the report.

[image]